# Check if an asp:Hyperlink href is empty? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, href

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyp" runat="server">TEXT</asp:HyperLink>
```

**MARKUP**

```
<a>TEXT</a>
```

**VB.NET**

```
If hyp.NavigateURL = "" Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

**QUESTION**

How to check if an anchor tag has a href attribute from code behind?

Comment: Double quote missing in id=hyp?

Comment: Is your HyperLink control within another control? GridView, Repeater, DataList, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing " around id="hyp" or was that just a typo?

You should be able to check if the NavigateUrl on a Hyperlink is an empty string, like you're doing.

> The URL to navigate to when a hyperlink in a HyperLinkField is
>   clicked. The default is an empty string (""), which indicates that
>   this property is not set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you create a `hyperlink` using `asp tags`

```
 <asp:HyperLink  id="aspHyp" runat ="server" ></asp:HyperLink>
```

Then you can check whether the href is blank or not using

```
If aspHyp.NavigateUrl = "" Then
   MsgBox("Href is blank!")
End If
```

If you create a hyperlink using `<a>`

```
 <a id="hyp" runat ="server">TEXT</a>
```

Then you can check whether the href is blank or not using

```
 If hyp.HRef = "" Then
  MsgBox("Href is blank!")
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

in html you can check by this

```
<%
if (your condition) {%>
```

tags to show...

```
    <%} %>
```

and when you want to do this in code behind, you should use this

```
 if(hyp.NavigateUrl = "")
```

{
write your code here ....
}